# Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer, $R=\Bbb Z[\alpha]$, and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $ R/mR$ is finite and find $|R/mR|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Here, $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ denotes the ring generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\alpha$. The first thing that comes to mind is considering the homomorphism that takes a polynomial $p(\alpha)$ to the polynomial with coefficients $ \bmod m$. This is a surjective homomorphism with kernel the set of polynomials in $R$ with coefficients that are multiples of $m$ which is precisely $mR$. So the quotient $ R/mR$ is isomorphic to the set of polynomials with coefficients $ \bmod m $. But there is an infinite number of these polynomials because for all $n$ in $\Bbb Z$ there is always a polynomial of degree $d\ge n$.

Comment: What is $m$ here?

Comment: Any integer in $Z$

Comment: $p(\alpha)$ is *not* a polynomial: it is only the value  of a polynomial function at $\alpha$.

Comment: So the order of $ R/mR$ is $m$?

Comment: @Km356 What’s $ℤ[i]/2ℤ[i]$?

Comment: I've edited your post. In the future, you should include all pertinent information somewhere in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\alpha$ is algebraic, let $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic polynomial of minimal degree with $f(\alpha) = 0$. (Such an $f(X)$ necessarily exists by the well-ordering of the natural numbers.) There is a surjective ring homomorphism $\varphi \colon \mathbb{Z}[X] \to R$ sending $g(X)$ to $g(\alpha)$. I will describe the rest of the problem in exercises, with hints hidden behind spoilers; I encourage you to try these exercises yourself first before looking.

Exercise $1$: show that $\ker(\varphi) = \langle f(X) \rangle$.

> The kernel of $\varphi$ clearly contains $f(X)$. On the other hand, $f(X)$ is monic, so one can apply the usual Euclidean division argument to show that $\ker(\varphi) \subseteq \langle f(X) \rangle$.

Hence, $R \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle f(X) \rangle$, and so $R/mR \cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})[X]/\langle \overline{f}(X) \rangle$, where $\overline{f}(X)$ denotes the class of $f(X)$ under the natural reduction map $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})[X]$. Note that $\overline{f}(X)$ is also monic.

Exercise $2$: show that $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})[X]/\langle \overline{f}(X) \rangle$ is a free $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$-module of rank $\deg(f)$. Conclude that $|R/mR| = m^{\deg(f)}$.

> Again, the main tool here is Euclidean division. A Euclidean division argument shows that the classes $\overline{1}, \overline{X}, \ldots, \overline{X}^{\deg(f)-1}$ are generators of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})[X]/\langle \overline{f}(X) \rangle$ as a $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$-module. On the other hand, use the fact that $\overline{f}$ is monic to show that these classes are $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks. The way you answer is by far the most helpful.

Comment: If $ \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is all integer combinations of powers of $\alpha$ then it contains all integers and so the natural reduction map ( regarding these combinations as polynomials in $\alpha$ ) is a surjective map to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with  kernel $mR = m\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. So $R/mR \cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ (since $\alpha$ is just an integer) and so has order $m$. I don't see why this reasoning is wrong. I probably have a serious problem with notation here.

Comment: @Km356: what reduction map are you talking about, exactly? (And what is the target of the map you're talking about?) I'm not sure what you mean by "$\alpha$ is just an integer", either. $\alpha$ is an *algebraic integer*, which means that $\alpha$ is an element of some ring (probably $\mathbb{C}$, in your case) which satisfies a monic polynomial relation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ (or to be more precise, the with coefficients in the image of the canonical map $\mathbb{Z} \to R$.)

Comment: never mind I see my error. I thought I could regard $ \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ as polynomials in the variable $\alpha$ and after applying the map the takes each coefficient to its residue mod (m) I could regard $\alpha$ as an integer again and thought that would give me $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, which is wrong.

Comment: @Km356: indeed. Glad you see the error, and glad this answer could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: Take $\alpha=\sqrt 2$. Then $R={\Bbb Z}[\sqrt 2] = \{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in{\Bbb Z}\}$. Working modulo $m>1$, we obtain $R/mR = \{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in{\Bbb Z}_m\}$. The order of $R/mR$ is $m^2$, where $2$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2$ over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I have a problem with notation here. Is $ {\Bbb Z}[\alpha ]$ all possible linear combinations of powers of $\alpha$ or is it as you wrote for $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: Its all expressions in powers of $\alpha$ with integer coefficients. Here $(\sqrt 2)^2=2$.